# Custom Build variables

Tags: powershell, build, custom-build-step, custom-build

My Company works with custom buildsteps based on Powershell scripts.

My task now is to verify whether it is possible to 'export' Variables form these scripts to the global build variables available in tfs itself?
Somewhat like `$env:build_Myvairable` (in script) `/ $(build.myvariable)` (on Tfs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set variables that can be used in subsequent build tasks in TFS/VSTS by writing:

"##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"

Out to the log... This will create or update a build variable.

Comment: How do i get  the Value from these custom variables in TFS/VSTS? is it $(build.testvar) or $(testvar)?

Comment: I tried this for the label sources step as the label format, but it did not work

Comment: Please post what you tried and what does not work in a new question.